# Anyway to display sites in iframe which have 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'SAMEORIGIN'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Am building a website where i need to display some websites in an iframe (or in a modal). But, some sites are not displayed because of 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' restrictions.

is there any way to overcome this?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edited. hope someone can help me now.

Comment: If the site does not want to be framed, than it can not be framed.

Comment: @Makyen, well, actually, am just doing the development part, i used r-kiosk plugin to test things (when i changed to full-screen mode by pressing F11, new pop-ups are displaying with the size i set). so, you are right there, it's because of that plugin. and, whole thing is actually under-review with client, i was just trying to be foolproof..